# Alias with gnome-terminal acting very odd

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, alias

Here is a line from my aliases file that makes it so whenever I open my terminal it opens jasonaccomp in the vim editor.

```
alias acc='gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd ~/Downloads; vim jasonaccomp'"'
```

after exiting the vim doc I see

```
bash: alias: /home/master/Downloads: not found
```

This all is before I even call acc.
To make this even worse, the following code when run in my home directory, works exactly as I would like it to. It opens a new terminal that opens jasonaccomp and when I'm done editing, the terminal closes.

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd ~/Downloads; vim jasonaccomp'"
```

Also the command acc when typed gives me > with a blinking cursor. How do I get rid of having to edit jasonaccomp whenever I open a new terminal? Also how do I have acc do what the above line of code does.

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 14.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is due to the incorrect use of single quotes, precisely single quotes inside single quotes.

From `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of
>   each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur
>   between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

So change the single quotes of `bash -c` into escaped double quotes:

```
alias acc='gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"cd ~/Downloads; vim jasonaccomp\""'
```